# How can i play music during setup progress in INSTALLSHIELD(Basic MSI)

Tags: media, playback, installshield-2010

when music played by this command:
`PlayMMedia (MMEDIA_WAVE, SRCDIR + "1.wav", MMEDIA_PLAYCONTINUOUS , 0)`
the setup will wait (freez) until the media finished it's play
so, how can i play the media in background when setup still working.

Comment: If we talk about an application to be used in a professional environment, I would suggest to abstain from doing that. If it is a game or the like, that's a different story.

Comment: nice tip. thank you but i want this for something like a game.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation on the website ( http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/InstallShield2011/mergedProjects/installshield17langref/LangrefPlayMMedia.htm ) you can specify the `MMEDIA_PLAYASYNCH` value, like so:

```
PlayMMedia( MMEDIA_WAVE, SRCDIR + "1.wav", MMEDIA_PLAYCONTINUOUS | MMEDIA_PLAYASYNCH, 0)
```

Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is still struggling with this, here is how you can do this on a `InstallScript` Project.

1. Add your music file to `Behavior and Logic\'Support Files/Billboards'\Support Files\Language Independent`. It is important to add your file under "Language Independent", otherwise you might face issues like files not being copied to the temp directory (that tends to happen with Disk1 for example).
   [image: Adding music files]
2. Go to `Behavior and Logic\InstallScript`, open **Setup.rul** and add this line (replace "NAME.wav" with your music file name) right after `function OnFirstUIBefore() ... begin`:

```
PlayMMedia( MMEDIA_WAVE, SUPPORTDIR ^ "NAME.wav", MMEDIA_PLAYCONTINUOUS | MMEDIA_PLAYASYNCH, 0);
```

For other project types there might be some difference with the Path variables like `SUPPORTDIR`.